# Could not initialize class com.mongodb.connection.MongoQueryAnalyzer using mongodb Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

So, I'm making this java program to try out some basic mongodb stuff.

```java
package sample;

import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Cursor;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("Species");
        DBCollection col = db.getCollection("asdfg");
        System.out.println("connexion made");
        Cursor cursor=col.find();
        System.out.println(cursor.next());

    }
}
```

In the collection I have already added few JSON doc entries (around 7 of them)
There is no problem with the data entries for sure
(ignore the typo for connexion in print statement, i did that for fun)

Ok, so the code works fine till `Cursor cursor=col.find();` but shows a ton of errors when i include this line in the code
`System.out.println(cursor.next());`

here is the error which i get for the code

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=53479:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\mysti\Documents\untitled\out\production\untitled;C:\Users\mysti\Documents\mongo-java-driver-3.3.0-query-log-max-size.jar" sample.Main
Oct 27, 2019 9:11:54 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
connexion made
Oct 27, 2019 9:11:54 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Oct 27, 2019 9:11:54 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1951}] to localhost:27017
Oct 27, 2019 9:11:54 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 11]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, electionId=null, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=799200}
Oct 27, 2019 9:11:54 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:1952}] to localhost:27017
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.connection.MongoQueryAnalyzer
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:222)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:207)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:113)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:488)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:483)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:245)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:483)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:80)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:818)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:805)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:851)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:152)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.next(DBCursor.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.next(DBCursor.java:60)
    at sample.Main.main(Main.java:16)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the similar thing happened whenever I tried doing any sort of read operations I've done till now, while i could easily add data without any trouble.
Please help me,Im newb.

Comment: Is it a maven or gradle project ?

Comment: gradle project.

Comment: Can you post the gradle build.gradle code?

Comment: oh sry wait a sec,while creating a project i just chose JavaFX(planning to implement mongo in it) ,it didnt ask for anything else and there isnt a build.gradle file. There is some .iml file though...

Comment: I just included the mongodb- java jar file inexternal libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize everything written in the comments.

If you see such errors with classes, try to change newer version for dependency of mongodb java driver in maven/gradle project or manually add another external jar for it.

For Maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For Gradle:

```
dependencies {
      compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.10.1'
  }
```

As an alternative, you can also download the mongodb-driver-sync jar from [sonatype](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/3.10.1/).

Detailed examples you can find in mongodb documentation for driver [3.10](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/driver/getting-started/installation/). 
Personally, I highly recommend you to use [stable versions](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) like 3.10.2, 3.8.2, 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

OK,idk how i actually solved it but i made a new project and added a maven dependency this time and its working well now. I think i didn't use the mongodb-java-driver.jar file properly which resulted in these errors.
Thx for reading :D

Comment: I suppose that you have changed version of mongodb driver. Because it looks like the error of specific jar file. And yes, maybe you won't have the errors w/ dependency instead of using external mongodb jar file.

Comment: :o Thx a lot dude, I made another dummy project which gave errors again. Using mongo 3.0.0 isnt giving me these errors and now its all good.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved the issue. Keep it up and welcome.